# Replace double quotes(")

Tags: java, string

Here my String is looking like :-

```
sTest = AAAAA"1111
```

I want to replace double quote to a back ward slash and a double quotes(`\"`)

I need the String Like

```
sTest = AAAAA\"1111
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String escaped = "AAAAA\"1111".replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

- API doc for [`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

*(Note that the `replaceAll` version handles regular expressions and is an overkill for this particular situation.)*

Answer (score 2):

`string.replace("\"", "\\\"")`

You want to replace `"` with `\"`. Since both `"` and `\` have a specific meaning you must escape them correctly by adding a preceding `\` before each one.

So `"` --> `\"` and `\"` --> `\\\"`.
And since you want the compiler to understand that this is a String, you need to wrap each string with double-quotes So `"` --> `\"` and `"\""` --> `"\\\""`.

Comment: Thanks Ronk for ur suggetion.

Comment: When you want to replace " with \", you also want to replace all other \ with \\. Hence the answer should probably be: `string.replaceAll("([\\\\\"])", "\\\\$1")` (replace \ and " with \\$1, given that $1 is the matched string in the regex).

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers are correct for the single situation given, for more complicated situations, you may wish to use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache Commons Lang.

```
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("AAAAA\"1111".replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\""));
```